# trouble geeting script to run with google workspace account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

When running a google apps script in google forms, the script wont run when a user in my google workspace tries to execute it.  When a typical gmail.com users tries to execute it, it works.  Here is a demo of the issue.

screencast of the issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5QhIbzMRyQ

i tried using multiple accounts and multiple devices. the problem seems to be isolated to my google workspace accounts.  No user accounts in my google workspace work.